# Java: this keyword preceded by class name

Tags: java, arraylist, this

I find a snippet in ArrayList.java from jdk 8:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E next() {
        checkForComodification();
        int i = cursor;
        if (i >= size)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
        if (i >= elementData.length)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        cursor = i + 1;
        return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
    }
```

The line: `Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;` looks strange to me.

I think `ArrayList.this` is equivalent to `this` here. Am I right? If there's a difference, what's the benefit of using `ArrayList.this` over `this`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If there's a difference, what's the benefit of using ArrayList.this over this

An Inner class has a reference to an outer class.  To use the outer class `this` you put the class of the outer class before it.

Note: In this case `this` is an Iterator and doesn't have a field called `elementData`

Answer (score 2):

The code you see is inside the class `Itr` which is an inner class of `ArrayList`. The notation

```
ArrayList.this.elementData
```

is used to refer to the enclosing `ArrayList` instance's field named `elementData`. In this case, simply using `this.elementData` would be enough. But if your inner class `Itr` declared a member named `elementData`, you would need the other notation to disambiguate between `ArrayList`'s member or `Itr`'s member.

Answer (score 0):

When your code is in an inner class, then this points to the inner class, so you need to disambiguate. Therefore ArrayList.this will mean the ArrayList instead of the inner class which in this case I assume to be an Iterator.

Answer (score 0):

That method is inside the private class Itr, which is the inner class of ArrayList. So basically if we want to access the instance variable of outer class we have to do "Class.this" instead of just "this" because "this" would access the current class and not the parent class.