# Java instance method different call ways

Tags: java, instance

```
class SomeClass {
   public void someMethod(){}

   public void otherMethod(){
      //Calling someMethod()
   }
}
```

Whats the difference when you call an instance method as:

```
 --> someMethod(); OR this.someMethod();
```

vs

`--> SomeClass.this.someMethod();`

Comment: You can't call a method like `SomeClass.this.someMethod();`

Comment: There are contexts where `SomeClass.this.someMethod()` is a valid method call (for instance, non-static nested classes).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java "this" keyword proper use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805295/java-this-keyword-proper-use)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947750/java-this-keyword-preceded-by-class-name

Comment: @VeeArr could you give us an example (maybe some code) where `SomeClass.this.someMethod()` would be a valid method call?

Comment: `class A{ void someMethod(){}  class B{ B(){A.this.someMethod();} void someMethod(){} } }` the `someMethod` in `B` hides the one in `A`, so you have to use `A.this` to call it.

Comment: Thanks @NickL :) I just realized about this while reading https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html (_Accessing Local Variables of the Enclosing Scope_ topic)

Comment: @NickL I just thought the last syntax is not a common scenario, so I posted a community wiki in order to let future reader find it easily.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference from doing:

```
//...
public void otherMethod(){
  someMethod();
}
//...
```

to doing

```
//...
public void otherMethod(){
  this.someMethod(); // `this` in this case refers to the class instance 
}
//...
```

Now if you would have

```
class SomeClass {
   public static void someMethod(){}

   public void otherMethod(){
      //Calling someMethod()
   }
}
```

you could do:

```
//...
public void otherMethod(){
  SomeClass.someMethod(); // as the method is static you don't need to call it from an instance using `this` or omitting the class 
}
//...
```

And lastly this syntax `SomeClass.this.someMethod();` would not be correct in all scenarios. An example of where this could be used (correct) is as follow:

```
class SomeClass {
   public void someMethod(){}

   public void otherMethod(){
      //Calling someMethod()
   }

    class OtherClass {

        public OtherClass() {
            // OtherClass#someMethod hides SomeClass#someMethod so in order to call it it must be done like this
            SomeClass.this.someMethod();
        }

        public void someMethod(){}
    }
}
```